Fail to compare a character from a unicode number vs. the actual character
I have in a ANSI file Perl script the following code:
use strict;
use warnings;
use Encode;

sub UnicodeDecHashNumsToText($)
{
    use open qw/:std :encoding(UTF-8)/; # Tell perl standard output etc. use utf-8

    my( $lText ) = @_;
    print "Orig Text = '$lText'\n";
    $lText =~ s/^#(\d+)/chr($1)/e; # e treats the replacement as code, not text
    print "Returning: (".length($lText).")'$lText'\n";
    return $lText;
}

# Comparing
# The 'got' value is obtained reading a normal file.
my $got = UnicodeDecHashNumsToText( "#8364" );

# The 'expected' value is read through a select statement 
# from a database in locale: en_US.819
my $expected = "€"; 

print "'$got' vs  '$expected' \n"; 
if( $got  ne $expected ) { print "FAILED\n"; } else { print "SUCCESS\n"; }

Output:
Orig Text = '#8364'
Returning: (1)'€'
'€' vs  ''
FAILED

The compare fails.
What changes or additions needs to be done for the compare to be ok?

Need a use utf8; so perl treats the contents of the script file as Unicode text, not bytes. (Assuming it's a utf-8 encoded file, of course)

@Shawn: Pressumably this is just after the Comparing comment.  If so, the following error is raised:
Malformed UTF-8 character: \x80 (unexpected continuation byte 0x80, with no preceding start byte)
Please provide a whole code for it to work. Many thanks.

Sounds like the file isn't in utf-8 then.

Perl expects programs to be encoded using UTF-8[1] if use utf8; is used, and ASCII[2] otherwise.
You didn't use use utf8;, and € is not found in the ASCII character set, so your program can't possibly contain € as you claim.
To have a literal € in your program, you will need to make sure it's encoded using UTF-8, and you will need to add use utf8; to tell Perl that.

Comments you made suggest you tried using use utf8; with a file that wasn't encoded using UTF-8. (It was probably encoded using Windows-1252.) Adding use utf8; is not enough; you need to convert the file to UTF-8 as directed above.


I think it actually expects utf8, Perl's extension to UTF-8. But it's probably a bad idea to rely on that.
String literals are 8-bit clean, meaning that encoding errors (bytes in the 80..FF range) are included in the produced string as-is.


Thanks for the reply. But I cannot get it to work. Please provide exact code. Ta.

Re "Please provide exact code.", Literally what I said: Make sure your file is encoded using UTF-8 and use utf8;. Your earlier comment suggests you did the latter, but not the former. Your file appears to be encoded using cp1252, not UTF-8.
